# Proof regarding the euler totient function

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Let $m$ be a positive integer, prove that $$\sum_{\substack{d\mid m\\d>0}} \varphi(d) = m.$$

---

Recall

$$\sum_{\substack{d\mid m\\d>0}} \varphi(d) = \sum_{\substack{d\mid m\\d>0}} \varphi\left(\frac{m}{d}\right)\tag{1}$$

and note that

$$\varphi\left(\frac{m}{d}\right) = \#\big\{b\colon 1\le b
\le m, \gcd(b,m)=d\big\}.\tag{2}$$

But

$$\{1,2, \ldots, m\} = \dot{\bigcup_{\substack{d\mid m\\d>0}}}\{b\colon 1\le b\le m, \gcd(b,m)=d\}\tag{3}$$

and hence $$m=\sum_{\substack{d\mid m\\d>0}} \varphi(d)\tag{4}$$

---

So this is the proof my lecturer has provided but I've not come across a lot of the notions used.

1. How is the equality in $(1)$ found?
2. Shouldn't the set used in $(2)$ be $$\left\{b\colon 1\le b
   \le \frac{m}{d}, \gcd\left(b,\frac{m}{d}\right)=1\right\}$$
3. What does the union symbol with a dot on top mean in $(3)$? Also, how is this equality found.
4. How is $(4)$ implied?

Comment: When you fill out the instructor assessment at the end of the year, be sure to mention that this lecturer uses many shorthand notations without properly explaining them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A more detailed answer.

1. For (1) note the following

$$\sum_{\substack{d\mid m\\d>0}} \varphi(d) = \sum_{\substack{m=dd^\prime\\d,d^\prime>0}} \varphi(d)= \sum_{\substack{m/d^\prime=d\\d,d^\prime>0}} \varphi(d)= \sum_{\substack{m/d^\prime=d\\d,d^\prime>0}} \varphi(m/d^\prime)= \sum_{\substack{d^\prime|m\\d^\prime>0}} \varphi(m/d^\prime).$$

2. Same idea as in (1).

$$\begin{align*}
\#\big\{b\colon 1\le b
\le m, \gcd(b,m)=d\big\}&= \#\big\{b=nd\colon 1\le nd
\le m, \gcd(nd,m)=d\big\}\\
&= \#\big\{b/d=n\colon 1\le n
\le m/d, \gcd(n,m/d)=1\big\}\\
&= \#\big\{n\colon 1\le n
\le m/d, \gcd(n,m/d)=1\big\}=\varphi(m/d).\end{align*}$$

3. The dot is a disjoint union. For each number $n$ in the list $A:=\{1,2,...,m\}$ there exists one number $d$ such that $\gcd(n,m)=d$. Then we can split the set in disjoint sets, each set correspond to the numbers on the list $A$ for which $\gcd(n,m)=d$ and we vary $d$ on the set of divisor of $m$.
4. Take cardinality in both sides of (3). Since the union is disjoint we sum the cardinaliy of each set in the right side. By (2) each set has cardinality $\varphi(m/d)$ then we sum $\sum_{d/m,d>0}\varphi(m/d)$. By (1) we are done.

Answer (score 2):

1) is by symmetry. We're just traversing the divisors of $m$ in the opposite order.

2) $b$ is coprime to $m/d$ if and only if $\gcd(db, m) = d$.

3) refers to the disjoint union: it is just an ordinary union, but we can put a dot above the union to indicate that nothing occurs as a member of more than one operand.

4) Take cardinalities on both sides of 3.